# c# datagridview checkboxes matrix

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to make datagridview checkboxes matrix to work in particular way.
Mandatory requirements are.

1. Only one checkbox in datagridview row can be selected.
2. One checkbox per row must be selected.

Program is reading file during start and is creating rows where 3 out of 5 columns are tick boxes column. I like to make it work in such way that only one tick box can be selected per row and make it impossible to deselect tick box completely so nothing in row is selected.

Currently to make sure only one tickbox per row is selected I am using this code:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {               
           for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
           {
           dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value = false;
           }
    }
```

Nevertheless as you see row 2-3 have nothing selected. How can I prevent unchecking checked box but leave ability to check other box in row?

[image]

Comment: I may be missing something; however, I feel you may be using the wrong control for what you are doing. A check box is used to signal that an option is yes or no. Using “multiple” check boxes to indicate a single choice is possible; however a single combo box may be easier to manage and IMHO more user friendly. I am guessing a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` may be an easier approach. Using a combo box removes your effort to validate that only ONE item is selected. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want, but may be try this:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.CellIndex].Value == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            if (i != e.cellIndex)
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code do not work unfortunately but I did not thought about such approach. I will try to follow you idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out issue was not really with code only with DataGridView property "EditMode". Once I changed it from default "EditOnKeystrokeOrF2" to  "EditProgrammatically" everything is working as intended.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            //on click reset whole row
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value = false;
            }

           // at the end make only last clicked cell "true"
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = true;

              //check if no atempt to uncheck checked cell
                 if (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value) == true)
                 {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = true;
                 }


    }
```